# Table of Clifford Algebras

Tags: solution-verification, vector-bundles, clifford-algebras, k-theory

Thanks to Hans Lundmark, I just found the table of [Clifford algebras](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_Clifford_algebras#Classification) $C_k=C_{\Bbb R}(0,k)$ and $C'_k=C_{\Bbb R}(k,0)$, $0\leq k\leq 7$. But, I couldn't understand some of the slots in the table.

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline\\
k&C_k&C'_k\\\hline
0&\Bbb R&\Bbb R\\\hline
1&\Bbb C&\Bbb R\oplus\Bbb R\\\hline
2&\Bbb H&\color{red}{\Bbb R(2)}\\\hline
3&\Bbb H\oplus\Bbb H&\\\hline
4&\Bbb H(2)&\\\hline
5&&\\\hline
6&&\\\hline
7&&\\\hline
\end{array}$

My bad. I forgot them again although I looked at Wikipedia. Can somebody please help me to fill this table giving also some ideas to remember them?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... The complete classification of Clifford algebras can be found in many places, for example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_Clifford_algebras#Classification

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks for the link. The purpose of my question is to get some ideas for filling the table.

Comment: I don't think $C_2' = \mathbb{H}$ is right. It should be $\mathbb{R}(2)$, shouldn't it?

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks for showing the mistake.